# How to write `tabline` function in vim?

Tags: vim

I would like tabs in Vim (not the gVim) look as follows:

[image]

Explanation:

1. Sequence number of tab (1, 2, 3, 4 etc)
2. Name of file (no path, no shortened path)
3. If there are more than one file opened, list them in a tab.
4. If there are duplicate tabs (hence the same file opened in several tabs) they should be highlighted.
5. If buffer is modified add `+` at the end of filename.

Could anybody help? I want to have something like this within my `.vimrc`:

```
set tabline=%!MyTabLine()
function! MyTabLine()
  ...
endfunction
```

Comment: In case you weren't aware, there's now a [vi.se] Stack Exchange site! You might get better luck with your question over there.

Comment: "I don't want to some magic plugin do it for me, but the actual code to place into .vimrc" those are the exact same thing.

Comment: I know, but in most cases plugins contain too much code to find the actual block I want o learn/use)

Comment: Then start with `:help functions`, try something and ask for help if something doesn't work and you can't find a solution in the doc.

Comment: @romainl, after reading `:help functions` it seems your answer it's what I look for, so make post and I accept it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've already wrote my desired tabline function. The behaviour is almost the same, except:

1. the `+` sign appears after tab number if any of buffer inside the tab is modified
2. tab contains only modifiable buffers (it don't clog the line with buffers of netrw file browser, help and read-only ones), but you can change this, just uncomment the desired lines

[image]

Here is the code:

```
set tabline=%!MyTabLine()  " custom tab pages line
function! MyTabLine()
  let s = ''
  " loop through each tab page
  for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
    if i + 1 == tabpagenr()
      let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
    else
      let s .= '%#TabLine#'
    endif
    if i + 1 == tabpagenr()
      let s .= '%#TabLineSel#' " WildMenu
    else
      let s .= '%#Title#'
    endif
    " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
    let s .= '%' . (i + 1) . 'T '
    " set page number string
    let s .= i + 1 . ''
    " get buffer names and statuses
    let n = ''  " temp str for buf names
    let m = 0   " &modified counter
    let buflist = tabpagebuflist(i + 1)
    " loop through each buffer in a tab
    for b in buflist
      if getbufvar(b, "&buftype") == 'help'
        " let n .= '[H]' . fnamemodify(bufname(b), ':t:s/.txt$//')
      elseif getbufvar(b, "&buftype") == 'quickfix'
        " let n .= '[Q]'
      elseif getbufvar(b, "&modifiable")
        let n .= fnamemodify(bufname(b), ':t') . ', ' " pathshorten(bufname(b))
      endif
      if getbufvar(b, "&modified")
        let m += 1
      endif
    endfor
    " let n .= fnamemodify(bufname(buflist[tabpagewinnr(i + 1) - 1]), ':t')
    let n = substitute(n, ', $', '', '')
    " add modified label
    if m > 0
      let s .= '+'
      " let s .= '[' . m . '+]'
    endif
    if i + 1 == tabpagenr()
      let s .= ' %#TabLineSel#'
    else
      let s .= ' %#TabLine#'
    endif
    " add buffer names
    if n == ''
      let s.= '[New]'
    else
      let s .= n
    endif
    " switch to no underlining and add final space
    let s .= ' '
  endfor
  let s .= '%#TabLineFill#%T'
  " right-aligned close button
  " if tabpagenr('$') > 1
  "   let s .= '%=%#TabLineFill#%999Xclose'
  " endif
  return s
endfunction
```

Comment: Would you like to extract it to a plugin, on GitLab?

Answer (score 1):

`:help setting-tabline` contains a lengthy description, including an example function that sort-of emulates Vim's default tabline. You can use this as a starting point. See `:help functions` for a complete list of available functions.

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.